# Which event type I have to register on element to track adding subelements

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, mutation-observers

I am lookig for the way how to be informed about  element has been added to my div.

The style element is added by 3rd party component and I just know into which element will be added.
I am able to track this down with DevTools with DOM breakpoint on my div, but it is probably internal feature of Chrome.

Is there a way how to listen on fired event related to direct subtree modification? Something like this:

`document.getElementById("my-div").addEventListener("subtree-modification", function(event) { ... my event handler });`

I found information about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) in the doc. Is it the way forward? Can you provide me some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MutationObserver will work. (In contrast, mutation events via `addEventListener` are deprecated and slow, best to avoid them.) For example:

```js
console.log('script start');
const myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");

new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
  console.log('Change observed');
  // Once the change is seen, don't need the observer anymore
  observer.disconnect();
})
  .observe(myDiv, { childList: true });


setTimeout(() => {
  myDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = 'span content';
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="my-div">my div </div>
```

The `childList: true` will watch for changes to any *direct children* of the observed element. If you want to watch for changes to *any descendant*, use `subtree: true` as well:

```
{ childList: true, subtree: true }
```

But deep observers are expensive - remember to remove them once they've accomplished what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, that can be done using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations:
const targetNode = document.getElementById('target');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
  mutationsList.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
  });
});

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Modify the observer element to see this in action:
targetNode.innerText = 'Updated content.';
targetNode.setAttribute('data-foo', 'bar');
targetNode.removeAttribute('data-foo');
```

```html
<div id="target">Initial content.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of usage, it simple [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) that watch on remove/add elements, note that I used setTimeout to remove `<li>` element after 1 seconds, and another one to add element after 2 seconds:

```js
function callback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    switch (mutation.type) {
      case "childList":
        if (mutation.removedNodes.length) {
          console.log("removed element here");
        }

        if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
          console.log("Added element here");
        }
        break;
    }
  });
}

var targetNode = document.querySelector("#someElement");
var observerOptions = {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true, //Omit or set to false to observe only changes to the parent node.
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);

setTimeout(function () {
  document.getElementById("el2").remove();
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function () {
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.innerHTML = "new Li";
  document.getElementById("ulElm").appendChild(newLi);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="someElement">
  <ul id="ulElm">
    <li> element 1 </li>
    <li id="el2"> element 2 </li>
    <li> element 3 </li>
    <li> element 4 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```